# Nedarim 51a bar kappara permitted to listen to rebbe’s wife’s singing

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, kol-isha, even-haezer

The artscroll talmud nedarim 51a brings shalmei nedarim, yaakov emden and einayim lamishpat who explain possible circumstances that could have permitted bar kappara to listen to rebbe’s wife sing at rebbe’s son’s wedding.

The relevant einayim lamishpat is here https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14885&st=&pgnum=101

The relevant shalmei nedarim is here https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37841&st=&pgnum=75

Can someone who reads hebrew tell me the reasons they bring for why he was allowed to listen to her sing?  I don’t know where to find r’ emden’s comments but if you know could you tell me what reasons he brings as well

Comment: I assume Rav emdens comments are found in the back of that gemarra

Comment: @robev Are they on Hebrewbooks.org

Comment: @robev Ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Einayim Lamishpat gives 2 reasons for it

1. the Rambam Semag and Shulchan Aruch, listening to a woman singing is only prohibited when one wants to enjoy it. Bar Kapara didn't have in mind to enjoy the singing.
2. There were also men singing alongside her who drowned the woman's voice.

The Shalmei Nedarim, bringing the Rema on Even Haezer 21:5 (based on Tosafos Kiddushin 82:), says that as long as it is not done דרך חיבה (loosely translated - a loving way) and it is done לשם שמים, it is allowed.
Additionally, Bar Kappara knew that he would not be aroused by the woman's actions, which based on the Ritva in Kiddushin 82: is allowed.

Rav Yakov Emdin, brought after the gemara section of the Nedarim tractate, also uses the reasoning of הכל לשם שמים and explains that possibly because it was a שמחת חתן וכלה it was permitted.

Comment: There's also the flip side question: why was she allowed to sing near him?